# Solspace User : Edit Profile - Avatar Uploading

Tags: solspace, solspace-user

How can I get the size of the avatar uploaded and inform the user if the file is too big? Indeed, it seems like the edition does not proceed for a certain size of the avatar file.

Answer (score 2):

When uploading a file too big for the Avatar restrictions, the error page displayed should already display a message such as

> **The form you submitted contained the following errors**
>
> The maximum allowed size for images is 50 kilobytes

If you're looking to fetch and display the maximum dimensions for avatars dynamically and *before* someone attempts to upload a too large avatar file, you'll need to dig this information up from EE's exp_sites table. The data is serialized and base64 encoded, so you'll need PHP to retrieve the data.